# Android / Java : Unable to find class/method from another project (already referenced)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Good day. This is my second roadblock in my path to Learning Android Development.

Well, what I am trying to do now, is basically trying to call a method from another project which I have already added as a reference project.

Consider example below (IDE is Eclipse):

- I have two projects with classes called ProjectA and ProjectB
- `ProjectB` has a method called `showToast()` whose job is only to show a toast.
- I already added `ProjectB` as reference to `ProjectA` via Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Projects
- In ProjectA, I instantiated ProjectB's class:

  ProjectB project_b = new ProjectB();
- Then I tried calling the method:

  `project_b.showToast();`

Any thoughts guys?

```
- Could not find class 'com.androidexample.test.ProjectB', referenced
   from method com.example.testproject.MainActivity.<init>
```

Comment: try cleaning and rebuilding your project.

Comment: Check and make sure your import statement for ProjectB class is correct. The IDE will highlight the import if it can't find the class. This should indicate a typo on your part.